# left join in linq and get the rows which have null value from right table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, left-join

I have this sql statemenet and now wants to right down this sql into linq c#

```
Declare @PageMenuId int 
set @PageMenuId=131 
select * from MenuMaster as M
left join DynamicPages as P ON M.MenuId=P.PageMenuID 
where  P.Id is null or P.PageMenuID =@PageMenuId
```

I have tried this but its not working for me rt now .

```
MenuMaster objMenuMaster = new MenuMaster();
            DynamicPageManager objDynamicPage = new DynamicPageManager();
            IList<MenuMaster> lstMenuMaster = new List<MenuMaster>();
            IList<DynamicPage> lstDynamicPage = new List<DynamicPage>();
            IList<MenuMaster> resultMenuMaster = new List<MenuMaster>();
            try
            {

                lstMenuMaster = GetAll().ToList();
                lstDynamicPage = objDynamicPage.GetAll().ToList();


                 resultMenuMaster = from m in lstMenuMaster
                            join p in lstDynamicPage on m.MenuId equals p.PageMenuID into gj
                        from subpet in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where (subpet.Id == null) || (subpet.PageMenuID == PageId)
                                    select new MenuMaster  {



                                    };

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _ErrorLog.CreateErrorLog(ex.Message, ex);

            }
            return resultMenuMaster;
```

Comment: I think you can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on the "I have tried this but its not working for me rt now ." part?

Comment: I have tried that code but its not return any record for me but same sql code return 39 records for me .